# Analytics can't track firefox's users

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-analytics, do-not-track

the title explain everything.
i used tagmanager and triggered events as it ask to and it works as i expect with all browsers exept firefox.
any other(opera, edge, lynx, i.e. and of course chrome) answer really well: they fire tags and convert events on analytics.

if you just wait for the REAL TIME user passing on the website if i use every kind of system and every kind of browser, **GA** register me and when clicking on trigger, itercept the event; but if i am waiting with FIREFOX on the website i can stand in ther for the 30 minutes but nothing changes, the user you can see in the "right now" panel is 0 (zero), same if you clink on the triggers trying to see if GA may catch the event.

So i think,...maybe GA doesn't know how to track firefox user or they just have a problem with FF browser to catching the real time events and it is possible it register some firefox events in the "normal" way, days later...NO!
in the traffic, public if i ask GA for which browsers users used...THER IS NO FIREFOX USER and that is no possible in 9 months in a website with 87% of users coming from Desktop (not mobile) noone use firefox, just me 1 person have to register a firefox browser.
don't know if i can install an extension to my analytics to track firefox events or if GA is Just kidding people use browser different from chrome.

of course i remove the "DO NOT TRACK ME" option from firefox, and MATOMO(the new PIWIK) register me, but GA NO!

help...may i install something to my analytics or just it sucks and it is better to use it nomore?

Comment: I just verified this with one of our websites at work, 4.95% total audience FF versus 4.90% FF users for a specific event -- within expected margins. Plain GA is working just fine. It looks like Google Tagmanager is beiing blocked by FF, see also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538852/google-tag-manager-not-firing-event-in-firefox

Comment: I think Firefox is blocking GA from making requests https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/05/31/using-google-analytics-in-extensions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is this one: if you browse with adblock, firefox refuses all the connections coming from analytics, not just advertisements.

Therefore, this is an adblock issue, not a firefox issue and not a tagmanager/analytics problem.

I found the solution by myself but thanks to everyone for the interest, especially to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2903251/peter-van-der-wal), who tried to help.

Comment: Not only "ad-blocker" blocks google analytics "firefox content-blocking" blocks google analytics ass well